# prevent component scan for unit test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a class as following

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.def" })
@Configuration
public class ClassUnderTest(){

    @Bean
    public void createSomeBean()
    {
    }   
}
```

I am unit testing this class using

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ClassUnderTest.class)
public class someUnitTest()
{}
```

How do I prevent component scan from happening when creating a test context from ClassUnderTest

Answer (score 0):

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc.def",
               excludeFilters = {
                   @Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                           value = {
                               ClassUnderTest.class

                           })
               })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It might help people if you post a short explanation of the code and how it solves the problem.